# element is not typed at array object and receive messages of error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I get this message In my const `Icons[link.label]`, but `Icons` has type:

*Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'iconsProps'.  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'iconsProps'*

I don't know how resolve this error

Code:

```
import { Icons } from './Icons'
import links from './content'

import * as S from './style'

export type PropsIcons = {
  color: string
  height: string
  width: string
  margin: string
}

const SocialLinks = ({ color, height, width, margin }: PropsIcons) => {
  return (
    <>

      <S.SocialLinksWrapper>
        <S.SocialLinksList>
          {links.map((link, i) => {
            const Icon = Icons[link.label]
            return (
              <S.SocialLinksItem key={i}>
                <S.SocialLinksLink
                  href={link.url}
                  title={link.label}
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >
                  <S.IconWrapper
                    height={height}
                    width={width}
                    color={color}
                    margin={margin}
                  >
                    <Icon />
                  </S.IconWrapper>
                </S.SocialLinksLink>
              </S.SocialLinksItem>
            )
          })}
        </S.SocialLinksList>
      </S.SocialLinksWrapper>
    </>
  )
}

export default SocialLinks
```

Icons.ts

```
import { Github } from '@styled-icons/boxicons-logos/Github'
import { Youtube } from '@styled-icons/boxicons-logos/Youtube'
import { Twitter } from '@styled-icons/boxicons-logos/Twitter'
import { Email } from '@styled-icons/entypo/Email'

import { StyledIcon } from 'styled-icons/types'

export type iconsProps = {
  Github: StyledIcon
  Twitter: StyledIcon
  Youtube: StyledIcon
  Email: StyledIcon
}

export const Icons: iconsProps = {
  Github,
  Twitter,
  Youtube,
  Email
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: just try to tell typescript `link.label` is one of the keys in `iconProps`. `const Icon = Icons[link.label as keyof iconsProps]`

Comment: Thanks! @MicFung I would like to mark your answer as solved!!

Comment: Thanks. just answered below.

Comment: If you're typing `links`, then you can assert `keyof IconProps` on the `Link`'s label property type: [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-keyof-object-qf6v4?file=/src/Links.ts:76-103) instead of casting the `link.label`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript cannot recognise `link.label` is one of the keys in `iconProps`.
Therefore, we can cast it explicitly to notify typescript.

**From:**

```js
Icons[link.label]
```

**To:**

```js
Icons[link.label as keyof iconsProps]
```